# MS Excel 2013 Basic Help, While Offline, Not Responding

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

Until about a week ago I could get basic help in Excel 2013.  I could search for something like "text functions" and got links to those pages.  Now I get no response at all after pressing enter or the icon on the right end of the search text input box.

Since I do not have the net at home I use this basic help quite a bit.  Anyone having the same issues or have a way to fix it?

I tried to find a listing of Excel 2013 updates on my machine to no avail.  I thought a very recent update might be the problem.

TIA,
Jim

PS:  Microsoft leadership are not on my list of favorite people for insisting Win 8, Office 2013, etc. must be internet connected with no local help etc.